# Inner join between three tables to get info

Tags: php, mysql, join

from the beginning I used this code to go from table A(category) to B(joined)

```
$query = "SELECT *  
    FROM joined
    INNER JOIN category
    ON joined.categoryid = category.categoryid
```

Now I have made a third table called 'userticket'. From the 'userticket' table I have a column called 'jid' that is a foreign key to a column called 'jid' in the joined table. Basiaclly it would be easy for me to show the 'jid' on the 'usertickets' table as numbers, but how do I join the tables so I can go from table A to B to C so I can get the info from table A (category) onto C (userticket)?

Comment: It's just another JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM joined j
  INNER JOIN category c ON (c.categoryid = j.categoryid)
  INNER JOIN userticket u ON (u.jid = j.jid);
```

You can remove alias but i think that it's better to get a clear code.

Answer (score 1):

Just take another join

```
SELECT *  
FROM joined
INNER JOIN category
ON joined.categoryid = category.categoryid
INNER JOIN usertickets
ON usertickets.jid = joined.jid
```